# How to efficiently track number of logged in users from a large userbase

Tags: sql, database

If you have a user base of a million users for a game but only expect a dozen to be logged in at once, how is best to structure things so you can display the number of active users on your website? You wouldn't want (I think) to do a naive `SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE logged_in = 1`

Comment: You know, this is tricky. Querying the database will fail for users who are abruptly disconnected. This should be done in the application level, which you let us know nothing about

Comment: What database are you using? E.g., with SQL Server, you *could* use the bit flag, with a filtered index.

Comment: @Adrian communicating data via the DB is a perfectly normal paradigm and regardless is the use-case we find ourselves in so you'll have to work within those constraints :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. First, put an index on the **logged_in** column. Secondly, and I'm assuming this was just a typo (missing select-column), if all you need is a count, this is your query:

```
select count(*) from users were logged_in = 1
```

You **could** keep a separate stats table to track any number of aggregates you want quick access to. And that's not at all a bad idea. But, adding an index should keep this particular query pretty quick. Once you start needing to report on other aggregate user stats regularly, build a stats table for that purpose.

Bear in mind, your stats table can often be pretty simple if/when you go that route:

```
stat_id : int
name : varchar
int_value : int
float_value : float
```

Then, each login just needs to ...

```
update stats set int_value += 1 where name = 'logged_in_users';
```

And each logout needs to ...

```
update stats set int_value -= 1 where name = 'logged_in_users';
```

And possibly a job to auto-log users out and "rebuild" the stats table periodically.

Comment: What if a user get abruptly disconnected? Power surge, internet conn dropped, etc. Not all disconnections are graceful, this should be handled in the application level, not in the database.

Comment: In general, indexing flag columns is useless due to their low cardinality.

Comment: 98% sure it's not useless in this case.

Comment: But, I'll allow you 2% of uncertainty to prove that the "general" condition of uselessness applies here.

Comment: isn't a "stats" basically just a way to de-databaserize a DB and store 'global variables'? It is the obvious simple solution but screams clunky to me.

Comment: I believe it was a recommended approach in [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101718.do). And it's not uncommon to store shared objects of various sorts in the database. And I think these sorts of "global variables" are one of the intended purposes for MEMORY-type storage engines.

Answer (score 1):

I would maintain a `logins` table, add to this table whenever a user logs in and when the user logs off, remove the entry.
The table could also have an expiry time so you can account for login timeouts and query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Logins WHERE LoginExpiry < GETDATE()
```

Comment: What if a user get abruptly disconnected? Power surge, internet conn dropped, etc. Not all disconnections are graceful, this should be handled in the application level, not in the database.

Comment: Depends on how you're handling the users? Can you add more detail?

Comment: There's a ton fo details to take into consideration. We don't even know op's application platform (php? ror? android? ios? windows?). I just think your answer underestimates the complexity of this problem.

Comment: If they have some application logic to control the `logged_in` column in the database then my approach will be as accurate as that column.

Comment: Agreed. But you are only taking care of the easy part of the problem: assuming the database will correctly reflect the real world. It's not wrong, it's just a small easy part of a larger and more difficult problem.

Comment: The question is specifically about the performance aspect of using the DB to find statistics, not a question about if using the DB in the first place is ideal.